# Shell script to generate the ip address

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following scenario.
I have a file with the input :

```
start-I/p      end-I/p          code 
10.35.210.1    10.35.210.255    User1
10.35.145.1    10.35.145.255    User2
```

I want to generate the ip address table in the following format

```
ip             code 
10.35.210.1    user1
10.35.210.2    user1 
10.35.210.3    user1 
10.35.210.4    user1 
...
10.35.210.255  user1

10.35.145.1    user2
10.35.145.2    user2
10.35.145.3    user2 
10.35.145.4    user2 
...
10.35.145.255  user2
```

Can any one help me with a suitable solution?

Comment: Should the input be fixed in such format or are you flexible on that ?

Comment: Yes..the input is fixed in such formant

Comment: And you have to do it in `bash` or any script is acceptable (like `perl` or `python` or `csh`)

Comment: only bash is acceptable....

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution, using `sed` and `seq` as dependencies, please try to understand the code Before using it.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "ip    code";
while read start end code
do
    if [[ $start != "start-I/p" ]]
    then
        startNum=0;
        for i in $(echo $start| sed "s/\./ /g")
        do 
            #echo $i;
            (( startNum *= 256 ));
            (( startNum += $i ));       
        done

        endNum=0;
        for i in $(echo $end| sed "s/\./ /g")
        do 
            #echo $i;
            (( endNum *= 256 ));
            (( endNum += $i ));
        done

        for j in $(seq $startNum $endNum)
        do
            (( p1 = $j % 256 ));
            (( j /= 256 ));
            (( p2 = $j % 256 ));
            (( j /= 256 ));
            (( p3 = $j % 256 ));
            (( j /= 256 ));
            (( p4 = $j % 256 ));
            echo "$p4.$p3.$p2.$p1   $code";
        done
        #echo $num1;
    fi
done < $1
```